# Apache Beam multi language "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported." error

Tags: maven, streaming, apache-beam

I am trying to use Apache Beam multi language explained in https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java-multi-language-pipelines/.
However when I run the same code showed in the tutorial(can be found here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/multi-language/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/multilanguage/PythonDataframeWordCount.java), I get the error when backend is Flink.

I ran the code with the command.

```
mvn compile -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCountPythonExternal -Dexec.args="--runner=FlinkRunner --inputFile=./data/sample.txt --output=./results/counts2" -Pflink-runner
```

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported.
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.visitPrimitiveTransform(FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.java:99)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:593)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:240)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:214)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:469)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineTranslator.translate(FlinkPipelineTranslator.java:38)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.translate(FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.java:54)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.translate(FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.java:115)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run(FlinkRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:323)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:309)
        at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCountPythonExternal.runWordCount(WordCountPythonExternal.java:174)
        at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCountPythonExternal.main(WordCountPythonExternal.java:181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.205 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-28T07:02:16+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/188M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing the Java class. The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing the Java class. The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported.
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.visitPrimitiveTransform(FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.java:99)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:593)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:240)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:214)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:469)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineTranslator.translate(FlinkPipelineTranslator.java:38)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.translate(FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.java:54)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.translate(FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.java:115)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run(FlinkRunner.java:104)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:323)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:309)
        at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCountPythonExternal.runWordCount(WordCountPythonExternal.java:174)
        at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCountPythonExternal.main(WordCountPythonExternal.java:181)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

When backend is Direct Runner, system shows trace below. Then stucks there. I ran the code using below command
I ran the code with the command.

```
mvn compile -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCountPythonExternal -Dexec.args="--inputFile=./data/sample.txt --output=./results/counts2" -Pdirect-runner
```

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building word-count-beam 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ word-count-beam ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/beam_projs/tmp_exp/word-count-beam/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ word-count-beam ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ word-count-beam ---
Jul 28, 2022 7:04:20 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.python.PythonService start
INFO: Running bootstrap command [python3, /tmp/bootstrap_beam_venv8817961971129663193.py]
/tmp/bootstrap_beam_venv8817961971129663193.py:69: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
  return distutils.version.StrictVersion(s)
/tmp/bootstrap_beam_venv8817961971129663193.py:71: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
  return distutils.version.StrictVersion('0.0')
Jul 28, 2022 7:04:20 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.python.PythonService start
INFO: /home/ubuntu/.apache_beam/cache/venvs/py-3.8-beam-2.40.0-da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709/bin/python
Jul 28, 2022 7:04:20 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.python.PythonService start
INFO: Starting python service with arguments [/home/ubuntu/.apache_beam/cache/venvs/py-3.8-beam-2.40.0-da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709/bin/python, -m, apache_beam.runners.portability.expansion_service_main, --port, 39435, --fully_qualified_name_glob, *]
INFO:root:Default Python SDK image for environment is apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.40.0
INFO:root:No image given, using default Python SDK image
INFO:root:Default Python SDK image for environment is apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.40.0
INFO:root:Python SDK container image set to "apache/beam_python3.8_sdk:2.40.0" for Docker environment
INFO:__main__:Listening for expansion requests at 39435
INFO:root:Missing pipeline option (runner). Executing pipeline using the default runner: DirectRunner.
INFO:__main__:Shutting down expansion service.
```

What could be the reason for that any help is appreciated. My aim is to make system work Flink backend, direct runner experimentation is just for seeing whether problem is related to backend.
You can find my pom.xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>word-count-beam</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <beam.version>2.40.0</beam.version>

    <bigquery.version>v2-rev20211129-1.32.1</bigquery.version>
    <google-api-client.version>1.32.1</google-api-client.version>
    <guava.version>31.1-jre</guava.version>
    <hamcrest.version>2.1</hamcrest.version>
    <jackson.version>2.13.0</jackson.version>
    <joda.version>2.10.10</joda.version>
    <junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
    <libraries-bom.version>25.2.0</libraries-bom.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-exec-plugin.version>1.6.0</maven-exec-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    <mockito.version>3.7.7</mockito.version>
    <pubsub.version>v1-rev20211130-1.32.1</pubsub.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.30</slf4j.version>
    <spark.version>2.4.8</spark.version>
    <hadoop.version>2.10.1</hadoop.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <nemo.version>0.1</nemo.version>
    <flink.artifact.name>beam-runners-flink-1.15</flink.artifact.name>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>apache.snapshots</id>
      <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
        <!--
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          -->
          <release>11</release>  <!--or <release>10</release>-->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>all</parallel>
          <threadCount>4</threadCount>
          <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Ensure that the Maven jar plugin runs before the Maven
        shade plugin by listing the plugin higher within the file. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>

      <!--
        Configures `mvn package` to produce a bundled jar ("fat jar") for runners
        that require this for job submission to a cluster.
      -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>${project.artifactId}-bundled-${project.version}</finalName>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-exec-plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>run-selenium</id>
                  <phase>integration-test</phase>
                  <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>direct-runner</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <!-- Makes the DirectRunner available when running a pipeline. -->
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

   <profile>
      <id>portable-runner</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <!-- Makes the PortableRunner available when running a pipeline. -->
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-portability-java</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>dataflow-runner</id>
      <!-- Makes the DataflowRunner available when running a pipeline. -->
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>flink-runner</id>
      <!-- Makes the FlinkRunner available when running a pipeline. -->
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <!-- Please see the Flink Runner page for an up-to-date list
               of supported Flink versions and their artifact names:
               https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/ -->
          <artifactId>${flink.artifact.name}</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>spark-runner</id>
      <!-- Makes the SparkRunner available when running a pipeline. Additionally,
           overrides some Spark dependencies to Beam-compatible versions. -->
      <properties>
        <netty.version>4.1.17.Final</netty.version>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-spark</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-hadoop-file-system</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>${spark.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
          <version>${jackson.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- [BEAM-3519] GCP IO exposes netty on its API surface, causing conflicts with runners -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
              <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
              <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>samza-runner</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-samza</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>twister2-runner</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-twister2</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>nemo-runner</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.nemo</groupId>
          <artifactId>nemo-compiler-frontend-beam</artifactId>
          <version>${nemo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
          <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>jet-runner</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
          <artifactId>beam-runners-jet</artifactId>
          <version>${beam.version}</version>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Adds a dependency on the Beam SDK. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-python</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- Adds a dependency on the Beam Google Cloud Platform IO module. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>${google-api-client.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
      <version>${bigquery.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>${pubsub.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled
             in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>${joda.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Add slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      <!-- When loaded at runtime this will wire up slf4j to the JUL backend -->
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hamcrest and JUnit are required dependencies of PAssert,
         which is used in the main code of DebuggingWordCount example. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
      <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The DirectRunner is needed for unit tests. -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
      <version>${beam.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>  <!-- "-jre" for Java 8 or higher -->
      </dependency>
      <!-- GCP libraries BOM sets the version for google http client -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${libraries-bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Check this: `The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported.`...also there are a lot of plugins not up-to-date..furthermore why is the surefire-junit provider hard coded in the pom file...

Comment: I already searched for "The transform beam:transform:external:v1 is currently not supported." with no success. I know that error comes from there. I put it all the trace, in case it might helpful. The pom file is the file generated after following https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that you are trying to use cross-language transforms on legacy (non-portable) Beam Flink Runner and Direct Runner.

Cross-language transforms are only available for Beam's portable runners.

Please see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/) for instructions for running jobs using portable Flink runner.

Comment: Can you also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73167858/not-running-beam-job-written-on-java-on-portable-flink-runner