# Not running Beam job written on Java on Portable Flink runner

Tags: apache-beam

When I try to run the simplest PortableRunner pipeline on Java, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: The Runner experienced the following error during execution:
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.apache.beam.runners.portability.JobServicePipelineResult.propagateErrors(JobServicePipelineResult.java:176)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.portability.JobServicePipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(JobServicePipelineResult.java:117)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.PythonExternal.runWordCount(PythonExternal.java:74)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.PythonExternal.main(PythonExternal.java:81)
```

However, I do not read any files anywhere in the pipeline or I do not sink to anywhere. My arguments are

```
--runner=PortableRunner --jobEndpoint=localhost:8099
```

and code

```java
package org.apache.beam.examples;

import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.*;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Simplest {
    public static final Schema SCHEMA =
            Schema.of(
                    Schema.Field.of("sentence", Schema.FieldType.STRING),
                    Schema.Field.of("count", Schema.FieldType.INT32));

    public interface WordCountOptions extends PipelineOptions {

        /** Set this option to specify Python expansion service URL. */
        @Description("URL of Python expansion service")
        String getExpansionService();

        void setExpansionService(String value);
    }

    static void runWordCount(WordCountOptions options){

        final List<String> LINES = Arrays.asList(
                "To be, or not to be: that is the question: ",
                "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer ",
                "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, ",
                "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, ");
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        p.apply("ReadLines", Create.of(LINES)).setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                .apply(ParDo
                        .of(new DoFn<String, Row>() {
                            @ProcessElement
                            public void processElement(@Element String element, OutputReceiver<Row> out, ProcessContext c) {
                                // In our DoFn, access the side input.
                                out.output(Row.withSchema(SCHEMA)
                                        .withFieldValue("sentence", element)
                                        .withFieldValue("count", 1)
                                        .build());
                            }
                        }))
                .setRowSchema(SCHEMA);
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordCountOptions options =
                PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(WordCountOptions.class);

        runWordCount(options);
    }
}
```

Although the manual suggests adding `--environment_type=LOOPBACK`, I also get error as

```
Class interface org.apache.beam.examples.PythonExternal$WordCountOptions missing a property named 'environment_type'.
```

Beam Version: 2.40.0
I started the JobService endpoint `docker run --net=host apache/beam_flink1.14_job_server:latest` as suggested.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This probably is happening because the Process that you start is different with the process of the terminal, so it can't access a path. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570555/exception-in-thread-main-java-io-ioexception-cannot-run-program-error-2).

Comment: I didnot do anything other than the tutorial. It is the simplest example on this issue.

Comment: I think what you are seeing here is a secondary error. Original error is probably logged separately (or swallowed somehow). Can you confirm that you have Docker running in the system ?

Comment: Yeah, I checked that.